# Ajuda com document.body.addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Eu não estou conseguindo entender onde está o meu erro no seguinte código:

```js
let createSquare = window.document.createElement('div');

window.document.body.addEventListener('load', function classicMegaManPlataformGenerator() {
  console.log(createSquare);
});
```

O meu plano inicial era apenas testar se eu conseguia criar várias `<div>` na tela de maneira aleatória, mas acabei ficando preso antes mesmo de chegar na metade do código. Tentei fazer uma `<div>` ser gerada e posteriormente exibida no console quando a página carregasse. Não funcionou. O que eu estou deixando passar? Eu sei que usando `window.addEventListener` funciona, mas eu quero entender por que usando esse outro método não.

Comment: O `document.body` é um `HTMLElement`, e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) vc pode ver que ele não suporta o evento `load` (nesse mesmo link dá pra ver que `window` suporta)

Comment: Ahhh vlw @hkotsubo dei mole numa parada boba